# How to refresh Notes of Social Panel in CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

is there any way to refresh only the Notes section in Dynamics 365?
I add a document when a button is clicked, and would be ideal if the Notes are refreshed after this.

I'm checking which is the id of the Notes element to get it with Javascript, but all of these are null.

```
document.getElementById("header_notescontrol")
Xrm.Page.getControl("notes")
document.getElementById("content_notescontrol")
```

@Utkarsh Dubey code works with legacy forms enabled, but I read this causes performance issues and I see when I open any record page remains loading for a big amount of time (you can interact with fields in the form,but page still loads asynchronously).

Is there any way to refresh notes section without legacy forms enabled?

Comment: Have you already ruled out `Xrm.Page.data.refresh(false)` ?

Comment: Yes, it only refreshes the footer, where I have 'Modified On' field

Answer (score 3):

```
function myFunction() {
    setTimeout(function(){ document.querySelectorAll('[title=NOTES]')[0].click(); }, 20000);
}
```

and then you need to make one change under `Administration -> System Settings -> General`.

> Use legacy form rendering == Yes

Comment: thanks for your reply, I get Mscrm.ActivityContainer = null

Comment: Open **Account** entity and then open any entry and then in browser console try to execute `Mscrm.ActivityContainer`

Comment: Thanks for this code, it works with legacy forms enabled.

Comment: FYI... https://superuser.com/questions/1218705/vshub-server-has-stopped-working/1219569#1219569 I'm not sure if you are the same person with the problem too but I noticed you started the bounty so I wanted to show send you a link to my answer that help the OP resolve so feel free to read it over, etc. https://superuser.com/questions/1218705/vshub-server-has-stopped-working/1219569#1219569